# web pack require() or not? react-hot-loader ES6 or jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am looking at the [react-hot-loader boilerplate](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate). 
I thought that using web pack was about serving javascript in one or smaller build.js(name defined), and that required you to use "`require('name')`. But it looks like the boilerplate is using ES6 "`import React from 'react';`"?

And using react-hot-loader or react-loader was some sugar ontop of javascript, but the boilerplate is using `export default class App extends`, but that is ES6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically they do the same thing. Since they are using [babel](https://babeljs.io/), it allows them to use the es6 syntax. Webpack handles it with loaders; you can see the babel loader in the webpack config.

This is the ES6 module syntax:

**ES6 Import**

```
import React from 'react';
```

**ES6 Export**

```
export default something;
```

**CommonJS Import**

```
require('react');
```

**CommonJS Export**

```
module.exports = something;
```